# Promise' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here

Tags: typescript

Sort of trying to figure out how asynchronous stuff works in typescript and when I run my compiler it yields this error. Here is the code I'm trying to compile:

**Printer.ts**

```
export class Printer
{ 
    public static printString(string: string, callback): void
    {
        setTimeout(
            () => {
                console.log(string)
                callback()
            },
            Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1
        )
    }

    public static printStringWithPromise(string: string): Promise<void>
    {
        return new Promise<void> ((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(
                () => {
                    console.log(string)
                    resolve()
                },
                Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1
            )
        })
    }
}
```

**Main.ts**

```
import { Printer } from './Printer';


class App
{
    public static run(): void
    {
        Printer.printStringWithPromise("A")
               .then(() => Printer.printStringWithPromise("B"))
               .then(() => Printer.printStringWithPromise("C"))
    }
}


App.run();
```

Then I just run `tsc src/Main.ts --outDir out/` and it throws at me the above-mentioned error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In your tsconfig [compiler options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html), check your `--target` and/or `--lib`.  The [`Promise` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) only exists for ES2015 and later.

Comment: @jcalz Well yeah I had to add the tsconfig file where I had to set the `target` field to `es6` and then it's become possible to compile and run it with `tsc --project PATH_TO_PROJECT --outDir PATH_TO_OUTDIR && nodejs PATH_TO_OUTDIR/Main.js`
I wonder if it's possible to do without `tsconfig` and set all the required stuff in the command line.

Comment: you can use `--target` on the command line afaik

Comment: @jcalz Yeah I see now. It works.

Comment: @jcalz: Post as answer please.

Answer (score 0):

In your tsconfig [compiler options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html), check your `--target` and/or `--lib`. The [`Promise` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) only exists for ES2015 and later.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

By default, TypeScript includes only the `es3` library during compilation, but promises only came with `es6` ([aka `es2015`](https://bytearcher.com/articles/es6-vs-es2015-name/)). Thus, you'll have to include `es6` in the `tsconfig.json#compilerOptions#lib` array - minimal example below.

---

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["es6"]
  },
  "files": ["index.ts"]
}
```

index.ts

```
const prom = new Promise(resolve => resolve('hello world'));
```

test script

```
npm i typescript
tsc # <- should not throw any error
```